# 405 Error when sending data from Jquery Ajax to ASP.NET Controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have an AJAX call and I am passing this data:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ data: holder, customer: customerID }),
```

holder is an `array` that looks like this 
`[1, 2, 3, 4]`

and customerID is an `int`

`3346759`

I am trying to pass it to this ASP.NET controller:

```
public List<CustomerQuestionsClass>
updateCustomersQuestions(List<CustomerQuestionsClass> items, int CustomerID)
```

and here is my class for CustomerQuestionsClass:

```
public class CustomerQuestionsClass
{
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    public int QuestionID { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to pass this data, I get a 405 error. When I take all the customerID stuff out of my ASP.NET Controller and ajax call the ajax call works, so I must be passing in the CustomerID incorrectly, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to stringify your data. Just send the data as an object. It is also unclear where your "CustomerQuestions" class comes in to the picture.

Comment: like this: `data: { data: holder, customer: customerID},`

Comment: `data: { data: holder, customer: customerID},` did not work

Comment: try this `data :{items:<you item list object>, CustomerID :<customer id >}`

Answer (score 0):

The data that your posting to your controller isn't matching its input parameters.
According to your method signature it expects a collection with the name `items` and a single int with the name `CustomerID`, so in order for your ajax call to work you need to change the name of your JS object's keys to match your action methods parameters.

View:

```
@model MVCTest.Models.CustomerQuestionsClass


<button>Send</button>

@section scripts{   
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {

        $("button").on("click", function () {

            var holder = [1, 2, 3, 4];
            var id = 3346759;

            var data = { items: holder, CustomerID: id};

            $.ajax({

                url: "@Url.Action("updateCustomersQuestions","Controller")",
                type: "POST",
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                contentType: "application/json"
            })
            .done(function (data) {

            });
        });            
    });
</script>   
}
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpPost]
public List<CustomerQuestionsClass> updateCustomersQuestions(List<CustomerQuestionsClass> items, int CustomerID)
{                         
    return new List<CustomerQuestionsClass>();
}
```